# Can RAID be accidentally configured twice?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, software-raid

I am renting a server from Hetzner, which had 2x 8TB disks. I *believe* they were listed as RAID 1 (though can't find anything to confirm that anymore), which I would have assumed would have given me 16 TB usable space as RAID 1. I then ran [this script](https://github.com/nix-community/nixos-install-scripts/blob/604327e7ab49dd4280ee40eba2f6b9ff76575f43/hosters/hetzner-dedicated/hetzner-dedicated-wipe-and-install-nixos.sh), which sets up RAID and logical volumes.

The end result, however, is a single (logical) disk of ~ 8TB. Could it be that RAID 1 mirroring is being done *twice*? If so, how would I confirm this hypothesis?

Here is `lsblk`:

```
lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda               8:0    0  7.3T  0 disk  
├─sda1            8:1    0    1M  0 part  
└─sda2            8:2    0  7.3T  0 part  
  └─md127         9:127  0  7.3T  0 raid1 
    └─vg0-root0 254:0    0  6.9T  0 lvm   /nix/store
                                          /
sdb               8:16   0  7.3T  0 disk  
├─sdb1            8:17   0    1M  0 part  
└─sdb2            8:18   0  7.3T  0 part  
  └─md127         9:127  0  7.3T  0 raid1 
    └─vg0-root0 254:0    0  6.9T  0 lvm   /nix/store
                                          /
```

`fdisk -l`:

```
fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: HGST HUH721008AL
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0D66DC9A-41E1-44B0-AF57-EDF422A7B4C4

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048        4095        2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2   4096 15628052479 15628048384  7.3T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 7.28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: HGST HUH721008AL
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1FE75135-DDF0-4DF7-B79D-4890D594D12A

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048        4095        2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2   4096 15628052479 15628048384  7.3T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/md127: 7.28 TiB, 8001425506304 bytes, 15627784192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg0-root0: 6.91 TiB, 7601349722112 bytes, 14846386176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

`df -h`:

```
df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                  6.3G      4.0K      6.3G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    62.9G     16.0K     62.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    31.4G      6.1M     31.4G   0% /run
tmpfs                    62.9G    456.0K     62.9G   0% /run/wrappers
/dev/disk/by-uuid/fa8731e9-00e6-44fa-aa0f-f86ce2a1ca03
                          6.9T      1.6T      5.0T  24% /
/dev/disk/by-uuid/fa8731e9-00e6-44fa-aa0f-f86ce2a1ca03
                          6.9T      1.6T      5.0T  24% /nix/store
tmpfs                    12.6G     12.0K     12.6G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs                    12.6G         0     12.6G   0% /run/user/1005
```

And [udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda](https://pastebin.com/hLBsUiJQ)

Comment: You made an incorrect assumption. Raid 1 is mirroring and two 8 TB disks mirrored will result in 8 TB of useable space, not 16 TB. (All data is duplicated and stored twice.) - To get 16TB of useable space out of two 8 TB disks you need raid level zero , striping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raid 1 = Mirror so 8TB usbale space with 2x 8TB Drives.
What you want is Raid Level 0, which is striping, giving you the 16TB of both drives as one logical device.